# What is the best approach to create a private DNS record that points to the private ip address of a pod within an EKS Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, amazon-eks, amazon-route53

I'm building an EKS Cluster for a Blockchain Network, and i have a requirement to create a private DNS record for each pod in the network (Note that these records must be resolved from outside the cluster).

Since i'm using the VPC CNI plugin in my cluster, every pod has an ENI attached to it, and, therefore, their ip addresses can be resolved within the VPC, and not only from inside the cluster. I just need to find a way to dynamically point DNS records in a Route53 private hosted zone to the ip addresses of the pods. So far, i've tried using the external-dns plugin, but, as far as i've seen, it won't work for pods, just for LoadBalancer/NodePort services, and Ingresses. Is there any workaround to make it work for my use case, or is there a better approach to solve this?

I've tried to use the external-dns plugin to create DNS Records pointing to the ip addresses of my pods, but didn't have any success.